# iOS - notifications (local / remote) just open the app, not showing alerts

Tags: ios, notifications

My app receives all the notifications local and remote. And also working fine with showing Alerts.

But when i press `Home` button and remove app from app stack or from recent apps. And after that any notification come, my app informed me for notification in notification bar. And when i tapped the notification, this is just opening my app (not showing alert). `[When app is in app Stack / recent apps and any notification arrives and after tapping on this will open the app and also show me alerts.]`

Any one have solutions or faced problem like this.

Thank You

Comment: How are you processing the alert in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Can you show your code in methods didReceiveRemoteNotification and didFinishLaunchWithOption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it will helps to you, you get notification info in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UILocalNotification *localNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if(localNotif) {
//get notification info
localNotif.userinfo
}
 return YES;
}
```